# Why I am not getting uuid id from firebase realtime database in react native app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

**I am able to set the UUID id and messages in the firebase database but when I am trying to get UUID from firebase I am not able to get that UUID. If you have any idea then please help me i am new in firebase**

```
const chatRoomRef = database().ref(firebaseMessages.CHAT_ROOM);

chatRoomRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
      console.log('User data: ', snapshot.val());
});
```

[image: Data I have get on console.log()]

[image: Data I have in firebase]

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are trying to access the keys (UUIDs) of the `children dataSnapshots` of the `parent dataSnapshot`.

If this is what you want to do, then try like this:

```
const chatRoomRef = database().ref(firebaseMessages.CHAT_ROOM);

chatRoomRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {

//loop through the children here

snapshot.forEach((child) => {

//print the key or UUID of each child

console.log('User data: ', child.key);

});

});
```